# Trigger an Action when ImageView is tapped three times in Specific time - Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-gesture

I have project in which I need to count touches on ImageView. If user touches the ImageView three times continuously, then trigger an action.

I have tried using `setOnTouchListener`, but couldn't find any method that can return an integer counter.

Here's abstract view of what I want to achieve:

```
if(touches == 3) {
//perform the action.
}
```

Can anyone tell me how can I count fingertouches on ImageView? Also if there's better approach, let me know.

Comment: Please try to have a counter/count that increments at each imageview click. Once the counter reaches 3 trigger your action.

Comment: @sumandas i have tried this, and it works, but the problem is - this will trigger an action on three clicks anytime. What i want is - three consecutive clicks! In this approach, user can click anytime, and when three hits, it triggers. the solution should be - three clicks in milliseconds should do the work. otherwise no action. do you think we can achieve that using this approach?

Comment: If there is another click outside the `ImageView` did you want the counter to reset?

Comment: @DanS i am not counting clicks of any other views other than ImageView, so no need to reset. I can reset only after my action is performed.

Comment: yes this would be fine and as it comes to mind, you can use "SharedPreferences" to store the click event timings and do the calculation on fly to see if the difference between click times is as you desired.

Comment: Another method seems, have a long variable that is static and stores system time in mili secs and update it with button click and update counter (+ and -) depending if the difference is less than one milli sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go mate plus [code snippet](https://gist.github.com/Pavneet6293/e247c31781ee8ffa4996681a45ce1713)

```
package com.pavneet.activitydemo.DB;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.pavneet.activitydemo.R;

/**
 * Created by Pavneet Singh on 20/06/16.
 */
public class TestA extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int i=0;
    private ImageView imageView;

    Handler handler=new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (msg.what==100){
                i=0;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_ab);
        imageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageButtontest);

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (i==0){
                    ++i;
                    handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(100,3000); // 3000 equal 3sec , you can set your own limit of secs
                }else if(i==2){
                    Toast.makeText(TestA.this, "Three Touch Clicked" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    i=0;
                    handler.removeMessages(100);
                }else
                    ++i;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Layout Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButtontest"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks pavneet will try this out and let you know as soon as i get on computer. :)

Comment: Your welcome , i have tested it ,hope this will make you happy. i would have done it yesterday but i was way past my bed time when i came across this post.anyway that's why we are here right, helping each other. Happy coding

Comment: thanks, it works very well. i appreciate your effort very much.

Comment: My pleasure Mr.Ajay P Prajapati

Answer (score 0):

Keep a count of `ImageView` touches in your `Activity` or `Fragment` or implementation of `onTouchEvent`. If you'd prefer 3 touches in quick succession, like a "triple click" use an `ArrayList` to record times from `SystemClock`. If the difference was below your threshold consider it touched 3 times.

Comment: i want specifically on ImageView only, yes i have considered implementing `onTouchEvent`, but in my case, its not what i want.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do some action every 3rd try this code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    public static int i = 0;
    ImageView myimage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimg);
        myimage.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case (R.id.myimg): {
                ++i;
                if (i % 3 == 0) {
//your logic here every 3rd attempt
// if you want to check it on only first 3 attempt if(i==3){some action}

                    Toast.makeText(this, "image is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, and this works as i said in above comments, but problem is i want 3 clicks to happen in specific time limit. for example, 3 seconds max to get three clicks, if not then reset counter.